# how to append typeahead dynamically by click?

Tags: angularjs

Am new to angularjs. and am using [this link](http://www.angularcode.com/how-to-create-a-facebook-style-autocomplete-using-angularjs/)  to create typeahead. 
It is working fine. but am unable to create this dynamically. 
Please refer a solution.

This is my code

```
$scope.addField = function() {
    var html = '<div class="form-group">
            <label for="area2">Area 2</label>
            <input type="text" name="area2" ng-model="doctor.area2" placeholder="Search Countries" typeahead="c as c.country for c in countries | orderBy:'+"'country'"+' | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:10" typeahead-min-length="1" typeahead-on-select="onSelectPart($item, $model, $label)" typeahead-template-url="customTemplate.html" class="form-control"   >
        </div>';

        var topScope = angular.element(document).scope();
        var elem = $compile(html)(topScope);
        angular.element(document.getElementById('more_Areas')).append(elem);
    };

<div class="form-group"  >
                <label   ><a  ng-click='addField()'>Add More Practice Areas</a></label>
            </div> 
            <div id="more_Areas"  >
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this, I've used it a couple of times.. and you can also specify a model for each new field you add by changing the ng-model to field.modelName

```
$scope.fields = [];
$scope.addField = function() {
    var topScope = angular.element(document).scope();
    var elem = $compile(html)(topScope);
    $scope.fields.push({});
};

<div class="form-group"  >
    <label>
      <a ng-click='addField()'>Add More Practice Areas</a>
    </label>
</div> 

<div id="more_Areas"  >
    <div ng-repeat="field in fields">
        <input name="category" type="text" ng-model="person.category" placeholder="Category" required/> <span class="alert alert-error ng-show="add-bro.input.$error.required">Required</span>
    </div>      
</div>
```

Comment: Yes. Thanks for your help. it is appending new one. But it is not working like typeahead

Comment: you need to make typehead tag instead of the input, I don't think this is the correct way to initialize a typehead

Comment: you need to include this
<input type="text" placeholder="Search Countries"
ng-model="selectedCountries"
typeahead="c as c.country for c in countries | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:10"
typeahead-min-length='1'
typeahead-on-select='onSelectPart($item, $model, $label)'
typeahead-template-url="customTemplate.html" style="width:350px;">

Comment: yes. i tried with also. it is just appending input. but not working like typeahead

Comment: actually tried with this <div class="form-group">
    <label for="area2">Area 2</label>
    <input type="text" name="area2" ng-model="doctor.area2" placeholder="Search Countries" typeahead="c as c.country for c in countries | orderBy:'country' | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:10" typeahead-min-length='1' typeahead-on-select='onSelectPart($item, $model, $label)' typeahead-template-url="customTemplate.html" class="form-control"   >
     </div>

Comment: you should change the typehead to use the array of categories instead of contries